# A problem related to $2x^3-3x^2-x+\frac{3}{2}=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, definite-integrals, roots

> let $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2-x+\frac{3}{2}$.Then prove that
> $$\int_{1/8}^{7/8} f(f(x)) \text d x\neq \frac{3}{4}$$

---

Factorising$$f(x)=2(x-1.5)(x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})(x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$$
$$f(f(x))=2(f(x)-1.5)(f^2(x)-0.5)$$
But i don't see anything nice from this.
Maybe if i could prove that $$f(f(x+\frac{1}{2}))=-f(f(x-\frac{1}{2}))$$ then the integral would turn out to be zero.

also i dont think we have to find the exact value of integral for second part if we could just set up an inequality or prove that the integral is negative we are done!

Please note that i am intersted in a proof without actually finding $f(f(x))$

Comment: Regardless of whether you think it will lead to anything, step 1 is (in my opinion) definitely to invest the 5 - 15 minutes to **edit your query** to explicitly specify $f[f(x)].$ I would do that **before** looking for elegance.  By the way, I think that $f(x)$ can be readily factored.  Look at the proportions between the coefficients.

Comment: @cosmo5 any ideas??

Comment: $f(f(x)) = 2(f(x)-3/2)(f^2(x)-1/2)$. How many times f(x) attains 3/2 etc.? I'll have to work on integration part.

Comment: @cosmo5 f(x)=3/2 has 3 solutions as shown by me in  this post

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore, we're done on first part. $1/\sqrt{2} < 3/2$. I believe this is correct approach.

Comment: @cosmo5  yes i didn't see that,thanks for your time but the second part is difficult

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have the right idea about exploiting some sort of symmetry in $f(f(x))$, but the integral doesn't evaluate zero.

Anyway, for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $$f(1-y) = 2(1-y)^3-3(1-y)^2-(1-y)+\dfrac{3}{2} = -2y^3+3y^2+y-\dfrac{1}{2} = 1-f(y).$$

Hence, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have$$f(f(1-x)) = f(1-f(x)) = 1-f(f(x)),$$ where we have used the above property for $y = x$, and then for $y = f(x)$.

Now, let $I = \displaystyle\int_{1/8}^{7/8}f(f(x))\,dx$. Replace $x$ with $1-x$ to get $I= \displaystyle\int_{1/8}^{7/8}f(f(1-x))\,dx$.

By adding these expressions for $I$ together, we get $$2I = \int_{1/8}^{7/8}f(f(x))+f(f(1-x))\,dx = \int_{1/8}^{7/8}1\,dx = \dfrac{3}{4},$$ and thus, $I = \dfrac{3}{8} \neq \dfrac{3}{4}$.

Comment: I'm really curious why they just wanted you to prove the integral isn't $3/4$ as opposed to proving it is $3/8$. Maybe the problem creator wanted to allow solutions which bounded the integral instead of evaluating it exactly?

Comment: very elegant!!Actually this came in an MCQ in which there can be more than one answer to be correct.I found in the  answer key that this option was not correct so i decided to reframe it as this question.As it was an MCQ  maybe the 3/4 was kept as an option so that the students  carelessly select it.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 It suffices to split the interval, then $I=\int_{1/8}^{1/2}\text dx < \frac34.$

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov could you please elaborate,

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Ready.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for the comment.

Taking in account the brilliant condition
$$f(f(1-x)) = 1 - f(f(x))$$
by **JimmyK4542**, one can write
$$I=\int\limits_{\large^1/_8}^{\large^1/_2}f(f(x))\text dx +\int\limits_{\large^1/_2}^{\large^7/_8}f(f(x))\text dx 
=\int\limits_{\large^1/_8}^{\large^1/_2} \big(f(f(x))+f(f(1-x))\big)\text dx =\int\limits_{\large^1/_8}^{\large^1/_2}\text dx,$$
$$\color{brown}{\mathbf{I = \dfrac38.}}$$

Comment: Ah! yes similar to the earlier one but still different(+1)

Comment: @cosmo5 Of course, thanks!